# Variadic Templates, Perfect Forwarding to functions with default arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have been using a variadic template that acts as an exception firewall in an interface between C and C++. The template simply takes a function, followed by N arguments and calls the function inside a try catch block. This has been working fine, unfortunately one of the functions I wish to call now takes an additional default argument. As a result the function name is not resolved and the template fails to compile.

The error is:

> perfect-forward.cpp: In function `‘void FuncCaller(Func, Args&& ...) [with Func = void (*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, double, const std::vector<int>&), Args = {const char (&)[7], double}]’`:
>   perfect-forward.cpp:69:41:   instantiated from here
>   perfect-forward.cpp:46:4: error: too few arguments to function

A simplified version of the code is as follows:

```
template< class Func, typename ...Args >
void FuncCaller( Func f, Args&&... params )
{
   try
   {
       cout << __func__ << " called\n";
       f(params...);
   }
   catch( std::exception& ex )
   {
       cout << "Caught exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";
   }
}

void Callee( const string& arg1, double d, const vector<int>&v = vector<int>{} )
{
   cout << __func__ << " called\n";
   cout << "\targ1: " << arg1 << "\n";
   cout << "\td: " << d << "\n";
   cout << "\tv: ";
   copy( v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>( cout, " "  ) );
   cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

   FuncCaller( Callee, "string", 3.1415, v );
   FuncCaller( Callee, "string", 3.1415 );  **// Fails to compile**

   return 0;
}
```

Should this code work or am I expecting too much from the compiler?

Note: I have tested the use of perfect forwarding with constructors that have default arguments and the code compiles and works as expected,

i.e.:

```
template<typename TypeToConstruct> struct SharedPtrAllocator 
{
    template<typename ...Args> shared_ptr<TypeToConstruct> 
        construct_with_shared_ptr(Args&&... params) {
        return std::shared_ptr<TypeToConstruct>(new TypeToConstruct(std::forward<Args>(params)...));
    };
};
```

works when calling the cfollowing constructor with 2 or 3 arguments...

```
MyClass1( const string& arg1, double d, const vector<int>&v = vector<int>{} )
```

Comment: (It should be `f(std::forward<Args>(params)...);`, by the way.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there's any way this can be achieved. The default argument values are not part of the function signature. They're only code-generation short-hands that are expanded by the compiler when you call the function literally. Similarly, `std::bind` won't pick up default arguments, either.

Comment: I thought it was something long those lines... Out of interest why does forwarding to a constructor with defaulted arguments work?

Comment: Well, you can call the function directly, which is what your code does (if you unravel all the template parameter substitutions). But in the original question, the function type itself is deduced, and that's where you lose the default argument.

Comment: @KerrekSB - could you explain your comment about unravelling template parameter substitutions in more detail please?

Comment: @tuskcode: I just meant that when you fill in an actual use case of the template, such as `SharedPtrAllocator<MyClass1>().construct_with_shared_ptr("foo", 1.5)`, then that template specialization says `new MyClass1("foo", 1.5)` in its definition (that's the "unravelling" I had in mind), so the default argument is available in that context. By contrast, the original code always says `f(params...)`, it _never_ says `Callee(params...)`. In other words, the argument to `FuncCaller` is a function _value_, not a function _declaration_. And the _value_ does not contain default arguments.